# Prove that $\gcd(a^2, b^2) = \gcd(a, b)^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

The problem's quite clear. Prove that $$\gcd(a^2, b^2) = \gcd(a, b)^2$$

This is easy to understand intuitively and using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic would be easy but I want to prove it by using the Divisibility axioms and the GCD. I have attempted it and am mentioning my results.

Here $d = \gcd(a, b)$.

$$d | ax + by \implies d^2 | a^2x^2 + 2axby + b^2y^2 \implies d^2 | a^2x^2 + b^2y^2 \implies \gcd(a^2, b^2) | d^2$$

I feel that this is not necessary. Please help.

Also, the proof can be generalized to $$\gcd(a^n, b^n) = \gcd(a, b)^n$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can prove that $ d^2 / gcd(a^2, b^2) $ by observing that $a^2 = s.d^2 $ and $b^2 = t.d^2$ for some natural numbers s and t. Hint: $d = gcd(a,b)$

Comment: @inquisitive Sorry. But how do I show that?

Comment: @inquisitive So you mean $$d|a \implies d^2 | a^2 \implies sd^2 = a^2$$

Comment: since $d = gcd(a,b) , a = c.d $  and $ b=e.d $ for some natural numbers $ c $ and $ e$ so, $a^2 = c^2d^2$  and $ b^2 = e^2d^2 $

Comment: yes you got it!

Comment: You could also write $a=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r} a'$ and $a=p_1^{s_1}\cdots p_r^{f_r}b'$, where gcd$(a',b')=1$ and $p_1,\ldots,p_r$ are the primes in common, then  gcd$(a,b)=p_1^{\min\{e_1,f_1\}}\cdots p_1^{\min\{e_r,f_r\}}$. If you take the squares then...

Comment: @inquisitive $d^2 | a^2x^2 + 2axby + b^2y^2 \implies d^2 | a^2x^2 + b^2y^2$ I doubt this step. I took it because I knew that both a and b were multiples of d hence $d^2|ab$. But if we are talking about higher n's then how should I do that?

Comment: this is correct since $d^2| a^2x^2 + 2axby + b^2y^2 $ means $\exists $ some $ w $ s.t $d^2.w = a^2x^2 + b^2y^2 + 2axby $ but since $ab = fd^2$ ,$ a^2x^2 + b^2y^2 = (w-f)d^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $d=\gcd(a,b)$, then $a=da_1$ and $b=db_1$ for some $a_1,b_1$ relatively prime.

Then $a^2=d^2a_1^2$ and $b^2=d^2b_1^2$.

Assume there is a prime $p$ which divides $a_1^2$ and $b_1^2$. Since $p$ is prime, $p\mid a_1$ and $p\mid b_1$ (if a prime divides a power, then it divides the number - basic property of primes). Contradiction, because $a_1,b_1$ relatively prime.

Hence $d^2$ is the GCD of $a^2$ and $b^2$.

To have a general proof, just replace the exponent "2" with "n".

Comment: That was very easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GCD is

$\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{min(e_i)}$ where $p_i$ is common prime factor of the two numbers and $min(e_i)$ is the smaller exponent of the $2$.

$\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{2min(e_i)}=\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{min(e_i)}p_i^{min(e_i)}=\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{min(e_i)}\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{min(e_i)}=(\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{min(e_i)})^2$